# How do I incorporate allow_destroy option into a custom nested attribute writer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

Working in Rails, I'm incorporating the cocoon gem to dynamically generate ingredient fields in my recipes form. I can get it to work using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but not using a custom nested attribute writer. For instance, before incorporating cocoon, my code looked like this:

```
#recipe.rb
class Recipe
# name:string
  has many :ingredients
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

  # the method below should do exactly the same thing as accepts_nested_attributes_for

  def ingredients_attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.each do |i, ingredient_hash|
      self.ingredients.build(ingredient_hash)
    end
  end

end


#ingredient.rb
class Ingredient
  # name:string, price:integer
  belongs_to :recipe
end



#recipes_controller.rb (just the params part)
def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, ingredients_attributes: [:name, :price])
end
```

In order to use the cocoon gem, I need to modify my strong params for ingredients_attributes, and refactor my recipe form and recipe model, and it's the last part that's giving me problems. I can make it work with the line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

but I would like to know how to incorporate the options into my custom attribute writer instead. If it'd be helpful to see the refactored controller and form code, I can post it too. Thanks.

Comment: Can i ask why you want to do that? It's much messier if you put in the controller rather than in the model..

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm not putting anything in the controller. The only thing that gets changed in my controller is strong params. Everything else is in `recipe.rb` file

Comment: Well, if you are rewriting the nested-attributes handling from rails, a good starting point is the actual rails-code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0fe76197d2622674e1796a9a000995a7a1f6622b/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L319

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your use case in defining your own `ingredients_attributes=` method rather than `rails` define it for you with the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which is more robust.

But if you have to define your own `ingredients_attributes=` for some use case, you could achieve the `allow_destroy` with the following:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, ingredients_attributes: [:name, :price, :_destroy])
  end
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ingredients_attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.each do |i, ingredient_hash|
      if ingredient_hash[:_destroy].present?
        #include logic to destroy the associated record
        #both for new records and existing records
      else
        #you also need to make sure you address the
        #case for existing records and don't just build
        self.ingredients.build(ingredient_hash)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned in the above comments of `ingredients_attributes=`, if you are to implement your own `ingredients_attributes=` instead of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you need to handle all use cases including existing records (both the ones that are marked to delete or not), new records (both the ones that are marked to delete or not), etc.

Comment: In this particular example there is no reason not to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` other than simply learning how to implement that option in a custom writer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still no luck in getting the method to work, but I'll keep trying. I think I need to understand better exactly what cocoon is doing in the background in order to get this working. Also, in this particular example there is no reason not to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` other than simply learning how to implement that option in a custom writer.  One of my Rails instructors argued that it's almost always better to write your own nested attributes writer because then you'll know exactly what it's doing and how to customize it more if need be, Testing that theory now!

Comment: Imho there is great benefit in using code that has been used, touched and improved by thousands of developers. Imagine all the bugs that already have been found. Your initial implementation was super-easy, until, owwwww ... deleting existing items. Next: checking if an item is new (create) or existing (update). Next: ignoring blank items. Next: ignoring when a specific field is not filled in. Next: handle one-to-one relationships. Not to mention: using a known standard other gems rely upon.